# Regular expression to extract values

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have this pattern and I need to extract values corresponding to 'key:' and 'value:'. I have tried a lot of variations for RegExp patterns but no success. Can anyone help me?

```
 [Element Mapping -- Key: 111111111 Value: MyValue - MyName, Element Mapping -- Key: 220002222 Value: My-Val - MyName ].
```

My expected values are individually:

```
111111111
MyValue - MyName
20002222
My-Val - MyName
```

Comment: Which language are you using? That will make a difference to people's answers.

Comment: @Dan: The OP has used the `java` tag.  I like too when the user mentions the language explicitly in the question, but I'm getting used to it being only in the tags.

Comment: I am trying to do this in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your regular expression

```
/Element Mapping -- Key: (\d+) Value: ([^,\]]*)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/cJLtqCP8j7

Comment: Thanks but I want to get rid of text 'Element Mapping' and 'Value'. It will be great to just have the values after : for all Key: and Value:

Comment: @Himanshi: Hence the captures in `()`.  If you pull out the two captured groups, you should have your desired values.  See the link I gave for example executing of the regular expression.

Comment: @Himanshi: See for example http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html on capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this with regex?

I would suggest parsing it properly with the same tool that wrote it?

Comment: Its the list of parameter values that I am getting from the previous page from the Request object which is getting serialized. This pattern is written in the toString method

Comment: @Himanshi: Do you have a deserializer for the object type?  That will be the most efficient and accurate.

Comment: No, its just that I can receive this on the other page with the help of request.getParameter which results in a string value only.